# saved search set value

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript2.0, clientscript

I cored a saved search, and when I logdebug the results appear as I want. but when I try to set the value to the destination field, there is no response with any results.

```
if(cust){
                var custSave = search.create({
                type: "customrecord_me_customer_sales_person",
                 filters:
                   [
                    ["custrecord_me_customer_name","is",cust],
                   ],
                columns:
                [
                      search.createColumn({name: "custrecord_me_customer_name", label: "ME - Customer Name"}),
                      search.createColumn({
                         name: "custrecord_me_join_sales_person",
                         sort: search.Sort.ASC,
                         label: "ME - Join Customer Sales Person"
                      })
                   ]
                });
                log.debug(
            "sales person"+JSON.stringify(custSave)
                );
                var custSR = custSave.run().getRange(0, 1000);
                        var cust = custSR[0].getText("custrecord_me_join_sales_person");//the result I want in
                        log.debug(
                        "join customer sales person"+JSON.stringify(cust)
                        );
                        return true;
                    
                if (cust.hasOwnProperty('custrecord_me_join_sales_person')){
                var salesPerson = cust.getValue('custrecord_me_join_sales_person')[0].value;
                //var salesPerson = currentRecord.getValue({"custrecord_me_join_sales_person"});
                
                currentRecord.setValue({ fieldId: 'custbody_me_field_deposit_salesman', value: salesPerson });
                        }
                else{
                    currentRecord.setValue({ fieldId: 'custbody_me_field_deposit_salesman', value: null });
                    }
                            
        }              
    }           
}

    return {
        fieldChanged: fieldChanged
    }
```

is there an error in my script (there is no error notification). thanks for answering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is so badly indented that you can't read it properly, so you didn't see you exit your code before setting the value.
Here a version of your code somewhat indented:

```
if (cust) {
  var custSave = search.create({
    type: "customrecord_me_customer_sales_person",
     filters: [
      ["custrecord_me_customer_name","is", cust],
    ],
    columns: [
      search.createColumn({name: "custrecord_me_customer_name", label: "ME - Customer Name"}),
      search.createColumn({
        name: "custrecord_me_join_sales_person",
        sort: search.Sort.ASC,
        label: "ME - Join Customer Sales Person"
      })
     ]
  });
  log.debug("sales person" + JSON.stringify(custSave));
  var custSR = custSave.run().getRange(0, 1000);
  //the result I want in
  var cust = custSR[0].getText("custrecord_me_join_sales_person");
  log.debug("join customer sales person"+JSON.stringify(cust));
  return true; /////////// HERE
      
  if (cust.hasOwnProperty('custrecord_me_join_sales_person')) {
    var salesPerson = cust.getValue('custrecord_me_join_sales_person')[0].value;
    //var salesPerson = currentRecord.getValue({"custrecord_me_join_sales_person"});
    currentRecord.setValue({
      fieldId: 'custbody_me_field_deposit_salesman',
      value: salesPerson
    });
  } else {
    currentRecord.setValue({
      fieldId: 'custbody_me_field_deposit_salesman',
      value: null
    });
  }
              
}              
}           
}
return { fieldChanged: fieldChanged }
```

1. some trailing `}` seems to persist, you may have not properly copy / pasted your code
2. you `return true` (exiting gracefuly without any errors or logs, like you told) before having the opportunity to perform your `currentRecord.setValue()`